# Use of "Please receive" in e-mails

Tags: word-usage

When I send an e-mail with an attachment (e.g. document) to somebody, can I say in the e-mail: "Please receive the document."? If not, what would be better?

Comment: No, that wouldn't work. You could try something like, "Please see attached."

Answer (score 1):

In a professional setting, to make sure the recipient notices the attachment, *please find attached* is commonly used.

*Please find attached the receipt for your recent order.*

This helps guide the recipient to see and open the attachment.